# Redirect user based on his Role in Jakarta EE web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-8, jakarta-ee-security-api

I have Jakarta EE 10 web application with CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition. My web.xml setting:

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>app/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I have settings for these security-constraint with recquired auth-constraint for access

```
/app/* is an application users area
/client/* is client path
```

For login action I have this code:

```
public void execute() throws IOException {
    switch (processAuthentication()) {
        case SEND_CONTINUE:               
            fc.responseComplete();
            break;
        case SEND_FAILURE:                
            fc.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid Credentials", null));
            break;
        case SUCCESS:              
            if (isClientRole()) {
                context.redirect(context.getRequestContextPath() + "/client/nets.xhtml");
            } else {                    
                context.redirect(context.getRequestContextPath() + "/app/index.xhtml");
            }
            break;
    }
}

private AuthenticationStatus processAuthentication() {
    return securityContext.authenticate((HttpServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
            (HttpServletResponse) context.getResponse(),
            AuthenticationParameters.withParams()                        
                    .credential(new UsernamePasswordCredential(username, password)));
}
```

SUCCESS part works as expected, but  SEND_CONTINUE part is still unknown behavior like described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64750354/on-a-successful-login-securitycontext-authenticate-returns-authenticationstat/77983880#77983880) and I can't find, how to control it.

So question is - what is a right way redirect user based on his Role in JavaEE/Jakarta EE Security?

Comment: Just  return a specific http response when unauthorized and the applications server will do this for you. Just define (in web.xml) which roles are "allowed" access to that resource ... There is no need to do this manually. See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522831/how-to-redirect-unauthorized-user-to-certain-jsp-page-using-declarative-role-b

Comment: what roles and which resource is allowed everything works as expected, my question is different - how to redirect successfully logged in user based on his role

Comment: This is exactly what is covered in the linked question. Simple solution is to just use the error page to redirect where you want or, based on a specific error code returned, check for the error code in a filter and redirect. This is a lot cleaner than polluting your code with manual redirects.

Comment: you mean this approach?
<error-page>
    <!-- Forbidden directory listing -->
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/client/nets.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

interesting... but in this case when app user tries access Admin resources it will be forwarded to /client/nets.xhtml also